# Could not find method compile() for arguments [project ':react-native-facebook-login']

Tags: android, react-native, facebook-login

I am facing this issue while linking the react-native-facebook-login in the app same as described in the steps of the android linking steps

[Image 1](https://prnt.sc/UKcnnOWr254W)

here is my package.json dependencies list: -

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@monterosa/react-native-parallax-scroll": "^1.8.0",
    "@notifee/react-native": "^5.7.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
    "@react-native-community/progress-bar-android": "^1.0.4",
    "@react-native-community/progress-view": "^1.3.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.4.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^15.4.0",
    "frisbee": "^3.1.4",
    "immutability-helper": "^3.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "native-base": "^3.4.15",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.0",
    "react-native-a": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-facebook-login": "^1.6.2",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.1",
    "react-native-firebase-push-notifications": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.38.0",
    "react-native-in-app-utils": "^6.1.0",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-localization": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-material-dialog": "^0.7.7",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-music-control": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-music-player-service": "^0.1.4-beta",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.16.1",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.24",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.17.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-super-grid": "^4.5.1",
    "react-native-swift": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-track-player": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-typing-text": "^0.0.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.23.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-timeago": "^7.1.0",
    "realm": "^10.21.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.2.1",
    "rn-sliding-up-panel": "^2.4.6",
    "toggle-switch-react-native": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.19.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.72.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.1.0",
    "schedule": "^0.5.0"
  },
```

I also changed the codes in relevent files as shown in the steps of this repository about android

so i am attaching the build.gradle dependencies for confirmation

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    // implementation project(':react-native-facebook-login')
    compile project(':react-native-facebook-login')
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:+") { // From node_modules
            exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
        }
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}
```

Please help me with this, i have looked at all the solutions but still no luck there.

Thankyou